# Stream video to TV over Apple Composite AV cable?

Tags: iphone, television

I'm using an iPhone 3GS (iOS 6.1.6) and would like to stream video from the Safari browser or an installed app to my TV over the connected [Apple Composite AV cable](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC748ZM/A/apple-composite-av-cable).
Is that possible?

Comment: according to they product info it is possible !

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. And you have one more option to stream to your TV at $35 or even $30 when on sale and that is [chrome cast](http://www.google.com/chrome/devices/chromecast/). And it is wireless!